# AWS API Gateway with ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs

whats the standard implementation i should make to implement an AWS API Gateway entrypoint with an ECS microservices structure?

I been trying to do it, but i get an ALB that is public and an API Gateway pointing to it, the problem is that the authentication is handled by API Gateway so the ALB endpoint is unsecure.

Thanks

Comment: Using a VPC Link?

Comment: Yes. Have you considered that?

Comment: Can't edit first comment, so I will write new one. You could consider using api gateway with private integration. Instead of public alb, you could use internal NLB. The NLB would privately route traffic to your ecs service.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty standard and well documented. Have you checked the articles published by AWS? I think [these articles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/access-private-applications-on-aws-fargate-using-amazon-api-gateway-privatelink/) would help

Normally you would have a private Load Balancer and need to setup a "private integration" between API Gateway and Load Balancer

[image]